# MongoDB C# Array Filters for Complex Queries

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Iam using MongoDB C#/.NET Driver version 2.11.5. Here is my collection structure.

CollectionName: Deployment

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60263b3279357e12775bfb21"),
    "version" : "P3-V1.0",
    "productId" : "6020f75d103d4895f12c88ec",
    "hierarchy" : "6020f8ad103d4895f12c88ed",
    "description" : "P3-T1-V1.0",
    "policies" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Policy-1",
            "description" : "Policy-1",
            "rules" : [ 
                {
                    "subject" : "abc.def@xyz.com",
                    "status" : "InProgress",
                    "comments" : "",
                    "updatedBy" : "",
                    "approvalId" : "8f7c8767-6613-4aa2-9b87-7778a42512bd",
                    "requestDate" : ISODate("2021-02-12T08:29:32.000Z")
                },
                {
                    "subject" : "ghi.jkl@xyz.com",
                    "status" : "InProgress",
                    "comments" : "",
                    "updatedBy" : "",
                    "approvalId" : "9e7c8767-6613-4aa2-9b87-7778a42512ee",
                    "requestDate" : ISODate("2021-02-11T08:29:32.000Z")
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Policy-2",
            "description" : "Policy-2",
            "rules" : [ 
                {
                    "subject" : "mno.pqr@xyz.com",
                    "status" : "InProgress",
                    "comments" : "",
                    "updatedBy" : "",
                    "approvalId" : "1a6c8767-6613-4aa2-9b87-7778a42512bd",
                    "requestDate" : ISODate("2021-02-12T08:29:32.000Z")
                },
                {
                    "subject" : "stu.vwx@xyz.com",
                    "status" : "InProgress",
                    "comments" : "",
                    "updatedBy" : "",
                    "approvalId" : "2z0c8767-6613-4aa2-9b87-7778a42512ee",
                    "requestDate" : ISODate("2021-02-11T08:29:32.000Z")
                }               
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

C# Class Names:

Deployment (has multiple `IList<Policy> Policies`)

Policy (has multiple `IList<Rule> Rules`)

Rule

1. What is the Update query to update status, comments and updatedBy fields in a Rule, given Policy.Name (for ex: Policy-1) and Rule.subject (for ex: abc.def@xyz.com)?
2. What is the Insert query to insert a new Rule object inside a Policy, given Policy.Name (for ex: Policy-1)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the question -

[Querying, filtering and updating multiple level nested arrays in MongoDB using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040747/querying-filtering-and-updating-multiple-level-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-using-c)

I have implemented the following and it worked as expected.

```
    var updateFilter = Builders<Deployment>.Filter.Eq(f => f.Id, deployment.Id);
        
    var updateBuilder = Builders<Deployment>.Update
.Set("policies.$[i].rules.$[j].comments", rule.Comments)
.Set("policies.$[i].rules.$[j].completionDate", rule.CompletionDate)
.Set("policies.$[i].rules.$[j].status", Enum.GetName(rule.Status))
.Set("policies.$[i].rules.$[j].updatedBy", rule.UpdatedBy);
        
    var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>()
                {
new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<Policy>(new BsonDocument("i.name", policy.Name)),
new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<Rule>(new BsonDocument("j.subject", rule.Subject))
                };
        
    var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions()
                {
                  ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
                };
        
    await _deploymentRepository.UpdateOneAsync(updateFilter, updateBuilder, updateOptions);
```